# Java - fields labeled private can still be changed in the main function?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I'm new to Java, and learning access modifiers. I learned that if you declare a field private, you can only change and read it (from another classes) by using get and set methods. Is this not true for the parent class? Because it seems that it can still be changed in the main().

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Employee John = new Employee(01, "John", "Smith", 20000);
            John.salary = 20;
            txt.setText("ID : " + John.id + "\nName : " + John.name + "\nSalary : " + John.salary);

        }
    });
}

public class Employee{
    int id;
    String name;
    String last_name;
    private int salary;

    public Employee(int id, String name, String last_name, int salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}


}
```

Comment: *"Is this not true for the parent class?"* that is correct. Also vice versa.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that if I made another class file and referred to it from there, it doesn't work if it's private.

Comment: Your code example does not show any parent classes, it does not show modification of `private` fields from a subclass or superclass, and it does not show a `main` method. So none of the things you asked are in the example. That does make it a bit difficult for people to help you, you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 types of java access modifiers:

```
private
default //when no access modifier is specified
protected
public
```

Now let's understand the access modifiers by a simple table:

[image]

Basically access modifier determines if a data member, method, constructor or class can be accessed **directly**. They can still be modified no matter what access modifier you choose. For a better understanding I suggest you to go read about **encapsulation**. This will give you a good example of why access modifier exist.

Comment: `default` is not an access modifier.

Comment: default is when you do **not** specify any access modifier.

Comment: That is not what your answer says.

Answer (score 0):

Here The Employee class is inner class Therefore private fields are accessible even though they are private because inner class itself belong to outer class.

The private fields wouldn't have been accessible directly without getter or setter ,if the class Employee was  outside MainActivity class

Only one class in java file can be public and the name of the file should be same as the class with public access. here you are able to specify both MainActivity and Employee as public since Employee is nested inside MainActivity .

So MainActivity is consider as only class here .

If you want to put Employee class outside MainActivity

then change the public access modifier to default i,e delete access modifier on Employee class . And put it outside .

Or you can create different file for Employee class where you can give it public accessibility and file name will be Employee.java

now sal will wont be accessible like  John.salary in MainActivity